# Are there any Design Guidelines for Documental Databases?

Tags: couchdb, nosql, document-oriented-db

Just wondering if there are any kind of guidelines for when you are designing a document-oriented db and I am talking especially about **CouchDb**.

I know that being schemaless things can take the shape that we want but, are there any best practices?

Thanks in advance! =D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jan Lehnardt recently wrote up a useful overview of data **modeling** (I would not quite call it "schema" design as you correctly point out).

http://blog.couchbase.com/document-modeling-rules-thumb

Comment: Thanks for the link! It has great info =D

Answer (score -1):

I don't know specifically about CouchDB, but there is something over in the [MongoDB Docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design) about Schema Design.

Comment: this isn't as relevant for CouchDB.

MongoDB requires consistent data schema for indexing, CouchDB does not. The map/reduce phase and normalize any schema-less data in to a unified index.

Comment: @mikeal, What do you mean with "MongoDB does require a consistent data schema for indexing. "?

Comment: MongoDB's indexes are based on keynames which means you can only have relationships with consistent data schemes. CouchDB's map/reduce allows you to introspect a document and emit a normalized index which means the data can be truly schema-less without limiting what can be indexed.

Comment: Ok maybe CouchDB offers more flexibility but MongoDB will not throw an error when a document doesn't have (one of) the keys that are indexed.